# Issue with libphonenumber-js library not formatting international numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get international phone numbers to format properly but it doesn't seem to be adding the spaces within the number, only for the country code.

```
let phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber('+3802342342345', 'UA');
return phoneNumber.formatInternational();
```

So the result I would expect to see is:

```
+380 234 234 2345
```

but instead I get

```
+380 2342342345
```

without the spaces in the actual phone number.

Comment: How are you getting the formatted number? [The documentation](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js) seems to indicate you have to call `formatInternational()` to get it formatted correctly. But all I did was search for the library...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yep that's what I call (I forgot to include that line in my example above, just updated my question)

Comment: hi your phone number is not valid it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your number is invalid. Some of the number formats I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Ukraine)

```js
let phoneNumber = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber('+3802342342345', 'UA').formatInternational();;
console.log(phoneNumber)
console.log(libphonenumber.isValidNumber(phoneNumber))

//+380 44 xxx-xx-xx  (international call to Kyiv)
let a = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber('+380444234245', 'UA').formatInternational();
console.log(a)
console.log(libphonenumber.isValidNumber(a))

//+380 45 94x-xx-xx  (international call to Brovary)
let b = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber('+380459434245', 'UA').formatInternational();
console.log(b)
console.log(libphonenumber.isValidNumber(b))

//+380 48 xxx-xx-xx  (international call to Odessa)
let c = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber('+380489434245', 'UA').formatInternational();
console.log(c)
console.log(libphonenumber.isValidNumber(c))

//+380 48 2xx-xx-xx  (international call to 6-digit numbers in Odessa)
let d = libphonenumber.parsePhoneNumber('+380482434245', 'UA').formatInternational();
console.log(d)
console.log(libphonenumber.isValidNumber(d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/libphonenumber-js/1.9.48/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```

The library seems to take the default digits together

Comment: Yep that was it. I didn't know it checks the validity of the number, I had assumed it just formats it simply based on the country code that you pass in and that's it. Thanks!

Comment: one thing to note that it takes together default numbers for example if `+380 48 2xx-xx-xx` it takes `380 482` together

Comment: @asalgan There're several possible formatting "templates" for a given country depending on the phone number digits. That's why it "validates" and formats only "valid" ones.